# Why am I getting "Agent error" when trying to perform a backup?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am implementing a Backup system for my Android app. I'm using a custom BackupAgentHelper to back up the shared preferences and a database file:

```
class CustomAgent : BackupAgentHelper() {

    val DB_NAME = "notesDB"

    val DB_BACKUP_KEY = "dbBackup"
    val SHARED_PREFS_KEY = "prefsBackup"

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //Backup note's database file
        val dbHelper = FileBackupHelper(this, DB_NAME)
        addHelper(DB_BACKUP_KEY, dbHelper)

        //Backup SharedPreferences
        val prefHelper = SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this)
        addHelper(SHARED_PREFS_KEY, prefHelper)
    }

    override fun onBackup(
        oldState: ParcelFileDescriptor?,
        data: BackupDataOutput?,
        newState: ParcelFileDescriptor?
    ) {
        super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Performing backup...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onRestore(
        data: BackupDataInput?,
        appVersionCode: Int,
        newState: ParcelFileDescriptor?
    ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Restoring...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState)
    }

    override fun onQuotaExceeded(backupDataBytes: Long, quotaBytes: Long) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed backup: The size is too big.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        super.onQuotaExceeded(backupDataBytes, quotaBytes)
    }

    override fun getFilesDir(): File {
        val path = getDatabasePath(DB_NAME)
        return path.parentFile
    }
}
```

I wanted to show a Toast message to let the user know that a backup is running, and also to inform them if they are any issues. However, if I run the app with the Toast messages, and execute the following adb command to request a backup...

> adb -s emulator-5554 shell bmgr backupnow com.byteseb.grafobook

I am getting this output:

> Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
>
> Package @pm@ with result: Success
>
> Package com.byteseb.grafobook with result: Agent error
>
> Backup finished with result: Success

And the Toast message is not shown.

But if I remove the Toast message lines or replace them with a println() function and execute the same command, I am getting this output:

> Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
>
> Package @pm@ with result: Success
>
> Package com.byteseb.grafobook with result: Success
>
> Backup finished with result: Success

Why is this error happening? And if I am not allowed to show a Toast, what else can I do to inform the user about backups?

Comment: "Why is this error happening?" – You can't show `Toast`s from non-UI threads, so that's likely throwing an Exception. "...what else can I do to inform the user about backups?" – You might not want to directly trigger any UI notice from your `BackupAgentHelper`, since you never really know when the system will run it on its own. Personally, I would just keep track of the last backup time in `SharedPreferences`, for example, saving the current time there at the end of `onBackup()`. If you'd like a real-time update for a backup request, you can set an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Comment: @MikeM Do you think it would be a good idea to use a BroadcastReceiver instead?

Comment: For the real-time update thingy? That could work, but broadcasting within the same app is rarely ever needed, nor is it generally recommended anymore. There used to be a dedicated support library class for it – `LocalBroadcastManager` – but that's long since deprecated, in favor of `ViewModel`s and observers and such. If you would want to do a `ViewModel`-type setup, you could basically tell the UI anything you want from your backup agent, but it will take a little more setup.

Comment: If you're set on showing some UI notice directly from the helper, you might consider `Notification`s instead. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, thank you. I did end up using notifications, but I used Toasts in the answer because the question used them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MikeM said, this was happening because I was executing the code from a non UI thread.

I solved it by using a Handler, this one takes care of running the code from the UI thread:

```
override fun onBackup(
    oldState: ParcelFileDescriptor?,
    data: BackupDataOutput?,
    newState: ParcelFileDescriptor?
) {
    super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState)
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    val runnable = Runnable {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Performing backup...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
}
```